# Some images in wordpress not showing up

Tags: wordpress

I got weird experience on my wordpress website. There is no issue when I am logged as an admin. but when I logout and check to other pages. the slider images are not showing up. I investigated the issue and found out that when I logged as an admin, the image source is written in DNS like `<img src="http://www.mydns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/background-3-768x458@2x.jpg" />` but when it is no authentication or just visit to other browser it shows like `<img src="123.12.23.12/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/background-3-768x458@2x.jpg" />`.

any idea how to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: That's an odd one. You might state what slider or theme or both you are using, also whether the installation has been moved from one environment to another. Assuming you've already tried re-setting individual slide images, cleared any caches, and double-checked slider-specific settings, next things to try would be disabling all other plugins and/or switching themes to see if behavior continues.

Comment: you're right.. I tried to deactivate my SEO plugin and it works now.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem about URL image can't display using https. You can check using inspect element from your browser.

[image: Inspect Element http://pepesrestaurant.ca]

I suggest you using image in your hosting self. You can optimize your content website using tools https://gtmetrix.com/ for analyze it.